# confirm my solution for range(f) is same as solution given on answer sheet

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$f:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $ is defined by the rule $f(x) = 2\lfloor x+1 \rfloor$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$

ive already established that this is not injective and not surjective but i think that info is irrelevant here.

Q. what is the range of $f$ ?

solution: $ range(f) =$ {${2n\vert n\in \mathbb{Z}}$}

my solution: $range(f) $= {$x \in \mathbb{Z} \vert x=2m$  for $m\in \mathbb{Z}$}

I believe my answer is equivalent to the one in the solution, can someone confirm?

Comment: Yes, your solution is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same, just replace your $x$ with $2m$ and you will obtain the same expression.

It's the set of even numbers, also commonly written as $2\mathbb{Z}$.